# Is the sentence "Why C treats array parameters as pointers?" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> Why C treats array parameters as pointers?

It sounds quite wrong to me. I would have been happier to hear

> Why does C treat array parameters as pointers?

instead.

Is the first sentence correct?

Comment: It's a _sentence fragment_ rather than a sentence. It can stand alone as a title, or an answer say (perhaps if asked "What would you say an important question we need to address is?"), but of course needs suitable context.  But it should have a full stop rather than a question mark as a title / heading, and a question mark if used as a response only if you wish to convey uncertainty about the appropriateness of your answer.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. This is actually the title of a GeeksforGeeks page, and my edit(the latter version of the title) was recently rejected.

Comment: C treats almost everything as pointers.

Comment: I'd say the first version is just a ***noun phrase*** - but "titles" aren't necessarily "sentences" anyway, so that's nothing unusual.

Comment: @rajah9 You have a valid point(er).

Comment: @FumbleFingers A noun phrase? How do you figure?

Comment: @Hannah: Technically speaking it might be a "fused relative clause" or something like that. But *syntactically*, it functions pretty much like a noun. Compare *I know **him**, I know [that] **he works**,  I know **the reason** [why / that] he works, I know **why he works***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, I see what you mean, although I disagree that this is how it's used in this case. Thanks for clarifying though :) Either way, it still wouldn't be a noun phrase, would it? Just because sth has a nominal function it doesn't automatically turn it into a noun phrase, does it? Or would you say that, for instance, an infinitive clause is a noun phrase just because it can take on the same function as a noun phrase? Also, how could it be a fused relative? (I don't now why I keep sounding condescending; my questions are sincere)

Comment: @Hannah: Despite being educated to degree level in English *language, literature* ***and*** *linguistics*, I really have very little interest in "the naming of the parts". Many of which are still even today inappropriately based on a framework derived from long-dead Latin constructions. I can understand that some "native Anglophone grammarians" might gain a better understanding of how English works by identifying and naming various categories and terms, but it's not obvious to me how this sort of thing helps people like the OP here, who's clearly not a native speaker in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers uh... ok. Haha – that was not the answer I expected in a discussion tagged "grammar", carried out on ELU (not ELL); nor was it the answer I expected from someone who nevertheless actually *uses* the terminology that (s)he apparently rejects... I totally see your point now though, and in principle I agree (it's often hard to see the practical use of theoretical grammar if you just want to know how to use the language). Might be a good idea not to mix the two though, just to avoid confusion? That is, if you reject theoretical grammar, it may be good not to use its terminology?

Comment: @Hannah: An awful lot of the relevant terminology has changed significantly over the past few decades (i.e. - *since* my time in academia, almost half a century ago). And in particular, I sense a widening gulf between traditional (prescriptive) ***grammarian teachers*** and ***descriptive linguists***. If you look at John Lawler's contributions here on ELU you'll see that he often uses different terminology, AND is dismissive of many of the concepts and structures still referenced by some of those "old-school" teachers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Haha, yes – you're absolutely right. And that's precisely why I wrote my first and second comment to you – because I was wondering about **your** use of *noun phrase* and *fused relative* in this jungle of different views. Imagine my surprise when I got the reply that you basically don't bother about it in the first place haha!

Comment: @Hannah: I like that linguists today are quite happy to refer to the ***nouniness*** of some specific construction used in some ***nouny*** context. That's the kind of "terminology" I can relate to much easier than having to defend my interpretation of ***why X does Y*** as a "noun phrase" - maybe it is an np, and maybe it isn't, but obviously *I know **why John likes it*** and *I know [that] **John likes it*** share at least *some* "nouny" attributes with *I know **John**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. And I never wanted you to **defend** your use of any terms – I was genuinely interested in your way of looking at it (hence my addition in one of my early comments that my questions were sincere). I did not mean to try to put you right in any way. No offence, I hope.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, I am a native speaker of English (going by definition) :)

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer: Sorry if my *clearly not a native speaker* came across as dismissive/offensive. Nothing to do with anything you've actually *written* here, obviously. It's just that I spend more time on ELL (the *learners'* site) than ELU, and practically every week we get questions there from people initially predisposed to see the construction *why **this is** true* (***a** reason*, hence ***a*** kind of "noun") as a valid "sentence" (asking a *question*) because they have trouble getting used to the fact that in English we reverse subject/verb for questions like *Why **is this** true?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Please don't apologize for something so inconsequential. I was not particularly offended by your presumption in the least. In fact, I put up the question quite hastily, when only the punctuation needed correction (my bad). And btw I've read some of your posts on the network and appreciate your formidable knowledge in English.